# Rest_assured test local rest web service got error "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have written a very simple code to visit my local web API server and get  Connection refused error. But Postmen or Fiddler are working fine able to connect the server and get the response back.

my code looks like

```
Response resp=  get("https://localhost/Members");
System.out.println(resp.getStatusCode());
```

the error message looks like the following:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:532)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>     at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1974)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:492)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1396)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)    at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1178)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)    at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
>     at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
>     at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
>     at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1596)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)    at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:160)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get(RestAssured.java:808)

Comment: show header/port in postman

Comment: There is one header "AccessToken", but I think if do not add this header I should get 401 status code not  Connection refused error, and there is no port in postman